# how to create SQL SERVER DataBase Backup on another machine using FTP / another machine on network

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ftp

I need to know How to  Backup SQL SERVER Databse on another machine using FTP as my Destination machine is Off network ***OR *** another machine on network.

Need to know step by step instructions

Comment: The backup is, usually, stored in a file. You can send it by FTP, do you want that to be automatized? Do your mean your PC is out your server intranet and do you want to send backup to it (is it a security risk?)

Comment: Yes,If it is possible and If not then I take backup on a PC with in network but not on server coz in case of server crash etc .I can't recover by Data from backup.